# Set http url in dialogflow webhooks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, google-assist-api

I am trying to enable webhook fulfillment in my Dialogflow agent. However, whenever I go to input the URL of my service, I get an error saying You can use only https:// in fulfillment url when "Google Assistant" integration enabled. I have no interest in using the Google Assistant integration. So how can I disable it so that I can send webhooks to my http:// service?

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have to use HTTPS  as per the documentation:

From: https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment/configure

```
Note that your webhook must use HTTPS, and the URL must be publicly accessible.
```

Comment: If you want to use Dialogflow, they gave the requirements. If you are unable to meet those you'll have to look elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same issue, here is how to remove Google Assistant :

1. Export your DialogFlow bot :

[image: export]

2. Delete the bot:

[image]

3. Create a new empty bot and set a http webhook :

[image]

4. Import your previously exported bot :

[image]

5. Now you should have your previous bot working & released from Google Assistant